# jQuery autocomple and knockoutjs observable arrays

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete, knockout.js

Trying to update knockoutjs generated list, when i use jquery autocomplete functionality and select some possible values. But list doesn't update when i call the addItem function inside Select method. Expected behaviour would be that selected item value are added to knockoutjs items array.

MVC3 example view:

```
<input type="text" id="Name"/>

<h4>Items</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>:
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: code"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var appViewModel = new AppViewModel();
        function AppViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.addItem = function (name, code) {
                self.items.push({ name: name, code: code });
            };

            self.removeItem = function () {
                self.items.remove(this);
            };
        }

        $('#Name').autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            delay: 500,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/SearchItems",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchText: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != undefined) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Name,
                                    value: item.Name,
                                    code: item.Code
                                };
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                appViewModel.addItem(ui.item.value, ui.item.code);
            }
        });

        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/vya7V/

Your problem was that you were instantiating a new AppViewModel in the `ko.applyBindings` statement, rather than passing in `appViewModel` that you instantiated earlier and are using in the `select`.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If my answer worked for you you should up vote it, and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I would but i don't have enough reputation :)